# How do I conditionally render one of three components using a select tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm trying to practice conditional rendering. I have three separate address components that are formatted in three different ways.

In the main component, App.js, I hold state for all the address fields and one for format. At the bottom of the form I have a select tag to choose one of three formats.

I have two problems, to update all fields, in my handleChange I am using computed property names in setState and a separate call to setState when I click the select tag to change format.

```
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    console.log(this.state)
   this.setState({format: e.target.value})
```

Upon entering info, my component is rendered, yet zip is '', and format is 'New York' for example. This is from auto-fill. Entering each field separately, still leaves incomplete data in state. I understand that setState is an asynchronous function, and that in this case using the functional style is preferable to the object format. How do I use computed property names and values in the functional approach?

The codesandbox is [Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/3kry17m735)

App.js, select tag and button

```
 <select value={format} onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <option name="format1" value="format1">
        format1
      </option>
      <option name="format2" value="format2">
        format2
      </option>
      <option name="format3" value="format3">
        format3
      </option>
    </select>
    <button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      onClick={this.handleSubmit}
    >
      Submit
    </button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div>
      <AddressComponent
        name={name}
        street1={street1}
        street2={street2}
        city={city}
        state={state}
        zip={zip}
        format={format}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AddressComponent>
    </div>
```

AddressComponent

```
const AddressComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {(() => {
        switch (true) {
          case props.format === "format1":
            return <AddressFormat1 {...props} />;
          case props.format === "format2":
            return <AddressFormat2 {...props} />;
          case props.format === "format3":
            return <AddressFormat3 {...props} />;
          default:
            return <AddressFormat1 {...props} />;
        }
      })()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: sorry, what are you asking for is unclear.

Comment: I don't see the problem, the code sandbox seems to work just fine. My browser (Safari) doesn't auto-fill the fields. Which browser do you have issues with?

Comment: I want to use the functional approach to setting state in this instance. How to I use prevState?

Comment: I see. You don't have to use functional components all the time, class components do have their valid use cases, and having a component state is definitely one of the most valid. That being said, with the current alpha version of React, you can use the “Hooks” API to introduce state to functional components: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html – currently everybody and their grandma is very excited over this in React land, but I would not recommend using the alpha version in production